# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore"

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, google-mlkit

im facing this error when try run flutter in ios simulator with command **flutter run**

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore":
  In Podfile:
    google_mlkit_text_recognition (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_text_recognition/ios`) was resolved to 0.5.0,
    which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
        GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore (= 3.2.0)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 2.6.0) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
        GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore (= 2.6.0)
```

i already try update all package with **flutter pub outdated** and update pods with this command since i using M1

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi && arch -x86_64 pod install

still cant run in ios simulator

this my pubsec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.3.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  provider: ^6.0.2
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^2.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.2
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  mocobaas_pkg: ^0.0.7
  http: ^0.13.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.4
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  # flutter_share_me: ^1.4.0
  flutter_sms: ^2.3.3
  url_launcher: ^6.1.3
  i18n_extension: ^5.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  camera: ^0.10.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad: ^20.2.39
  pdf: ^3.8.1
  gallery_saver: ^2.3.2
  dio: ^4.0.6
  native_device_orientation: ^1.1.4
  google_mlkit_text_recognition: ^0.5.0
  pinenacl: ^0.5.1
  string_similarity: ^2.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.0
  image: ^3.2.0
  exif: ^3.1.2
  mobile_scanner: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  printing: ^5.9.2
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.5
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.3.0
  grouped_list: ^5.1.2
  emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.3.1
  local_auth: ^2.1.2
  flutter_contacts: ^1.1.5
  custom_pin_screen: ^0.3.0
  tutorial_coach_mark: ^1.2.4
  elliptic: ^0.3.8
  ninja: ^3.0.7
  cryptography: ^2.0.5
  jose: ^0.3.2
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.6.0
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  janus_client: ^2.2.8
  flutter_webrtc: ^0.9.11
  stop_watch_timer: ^2.0.0
```

this is my Podfile, and im never find Podfile.lock in my ios folder, i dont know about this since some solution always mention about remove Podfile.lock

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup


target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: The next release is scheduled on 2023 Q1, before that, you can try this tweak to work around the pod compatibility issue: https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/254418199#comment55